# How can I get a list of nested dictionary keys as dot separated strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'sa': 11, 'sb': 22, 'sc': {'ssa': 111, 'ssb': 222}}, 'c': 3}
```

I want a list of all the keys whose values aren't other dicts, but represented by their dot notation (assuming you 'dot' at each level of the dict). To put it another way, I want the compound, dot-notation key for all values who have no children.

For example, for the above dict, I would like to get (not necessarily in any order):

```
['a',
 'b.sa',
 'b.sb',
 'b.sc.ssa',
 'b.sc.ssb',
 'c']
```

Comment: Try to implement some sort of a recursive function. Please show any attempts that you have made yourself

Comment: I should have included my example.  I was not recursing properly - brain lapse, I suppose.  Thanks for the criticism & noted for next time.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to solve this problem but this should get you started.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'sa': 11, 'sb': 22, 'sc': {'ssa': 111, 'ssb': 222}}, 'c': 3}

def dotter(d, key, dots):

    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            dotter(d[k], key + '.' + k if key else k, dots)
    else:
        dots.append(key)

    return dots

print dotter(d, '', [])
```

Comment: Interestingly (to me), I added defaults for keys and dots in the function args so you could just call with `dotter(d)`, but subsequent calls hold the results from last time and append to them, so if I `dotter(d)` then `dotter(e)`, the second call will return both the results of d and e.  I'm sure there's a fine explanation for this, but I don't know it.

Regardless, thanks for the help.  Works like a charm.

Comment: This is OT, but for any googlers, the "interesting" tidbit from above is explained nicely here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'sa': 11, 'sb': 22, 'sc': {'ssa': 111, 'ssb': 222}}, 'c': 3} 
def fun(k, d, pre):
    path = '%s.%s' % (pre, k) if pre else k
    return path if type(d[k]) is not dict else ",".join([fun(i,d[k], path) for i in d[k]])

print ",".join([fun(k,d, '') for k in d]).split(',')
```

OUTPUT

> ['a', 'c', 'b.sc.ssa', 'b.sc.ssb', 'b.sb', 'b.sa']

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the dict with its values

```
def dotter(mixed, key='', dots={}):
    if isinstance(mixed, dict):
        for (k, v) in mixed.items():
            dotter(mixed[k], '%s.%s' % (key, k) if key else k)
    else:
        dots[key] = mixed

    return dots

>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'sa': 11, 'sb': 22, 'sc': {'ssa': 111, 'ssb': 222}}, 'c': 3}
>>> dotted_dict = dotter(d)
>>> print(dotted_dict)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b.sa': 11, 'b.sb': 22, 'b.sc.ssb': 222, 'b.sc.ssa': 111}
```